# Error when using ADF to copy from SQL Server to ADW

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am getting the below error while using ADF, my source is an on-premise SQL Server and destination is ADW. Please shed some light on this:

> Database operation failed. Error message from database execution :
>
> ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Query aborted-- the maximum reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while reading from an external source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows processed.
>   (/22799e45-a078-4f43-9050-87294328db61/Data.28013af9-5443-4bc1-bfd4-b0299552069d.txt)Column ordinal: 4, Expected data type: VARCHAR(800) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, Offending value:

Comment: Does ADF Not copies the blank values to the ADW?

Comment: Looks like it stopped on error with the first row. Check the values in the row against the table's columns to ensure you aren't trying to load data that isn't permitted/supported by the column. E.g. null into not-null column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the varchar(MAX) with HASH Distribution as my source conatained a text datatype and it contained some values larger then 8k character and polybase do not support max values,

So had to copy the data without polybase and use varchar(MAX) in place of text.

When I ran the pipeline all the data was copied into the ADW.